# constraint on all numerical tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to put a constraint on all numerical columns, this is what I tried:
Everything has to be possitive

```
ALTER TABLE * ADD CONSTRAINT Checknumbers CHECK ( > 0 )
```

This isn't working but I can't find a solution for it.

Is their any other syntax that I can use or do I need to do it manualy for each table?

Comment: There's no general syntax in SQL to apply a constraint to multiple tables. There may be for a specific product but you haven't included a tag to tell us what RDBMS you're using.

Comment: I am using oracle - Apex

Comment: I've added some tags for that.

Comment: this has nothing to do with Apex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to create a separate constraint for each column in each table.  You could potentially write a bit of dynamic SQL for this

```
DECLARE
  l_sql_stmt VARCHAR2(1000);
BEGIN
  FOR x IN (SELECT *
              FROM user_tab_columns
             WHERE data_type = 'NUMBER'
               AND table_name in (SELECT table_name
                                    FROM user_tables
                                   WHERE dropped = 'NO' )
  LOOP
    l_sql_stmt := 'ALTER TABLE ' || x.table_name || 
                  '  ADD CONSTRAINT chk_' || x.table_name || '_' || x.column_name ||
                  ' CHECK( ' || x.column_name || ' > 0)';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_sql_stmt;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

For every numeric column in every table in the current schema, this will attempt to create a check constraint.  The constraint name is limited to 30 characters so if the sum of the length of the table name and the column name is more than 25, this will attempt to generate an invalid identifier.  You'd need to figure out an alternate way of generating the constraint name (or you could let the system generate a name).  This also won't handle case-sensitive identifiers if you happen to have any of those.  You'd need to double-quote the identifiers if that is an issue for you.

Comment: Not sure if dropped tables that are in the recycle bin still get an entry in user_tab_columns, but it might be worth checking DROPPED = 'NO'